# Remove Dynamically added Textfield IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm having some trouble dynamically removing UITextFields from my scrollview.
I can add 2 UITextFields Dynamically. 
To remove UITextFields i am using the bellow given code

```
[dynamicUITextFields removeFromSuperview];
```

but only one UITextFields is removed and one Remains as it is .

I want both UITextFields to be removed

thanks in Advance

Comment: Can you please add some code.. then only people will suggest some solution.

Comment: When I see only one removeFromSuperview invocation, I expect to see only one view removed.  Please post more code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I totally agree your solution. But it will remove all the UITextField from the current view

**Step 1** Add the new added UITextField to Array

**Step 2** Loop the array and remove the UITextField from SuperView

```
    for(UITextField *textField in containerArray){
       [textField removeFromSuperview];
     }
```

Comment: So you *don't* totally agree with the other solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove all the `UITextField` from a View, the use the following code.

```
UIView *container=self.scrollView;

for(UITextField *textField in container.subviews){
    if([textField isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]){
        [textField removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```

Cheers.